# Enable site audit setting on all site collections

Tags: sharepoint-online, auditing, site-settings

What is fastest way to enable site audit settings on many different site collections?

Answer (score -1):

The best way would be to use PowerShell PnP for SPOnline.

Here is one example: https://jerryyasir.wordpress.com/2016/04/11/enable-auditing-sharepoint-online-site-collection/